# Understanding script from closed server

Tags: javascript

I am interested if it is possible to understand what script something.com has if you have no access to reach `http` page. Any possible ways?

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){       
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
        method: 'POST',
        action: 'xhttp',
        url: 'http://something.com',
        data: 'action=1'
    }, function(data) {
        eval(data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're tring to do is very close to Hacking.
You can use Fiddler to create some special request (changing for example `data` parameter and guessing the behavior of the WS that stands behind.

Another thing you can do is watching the return value of the async function

```
 eval(data);
```

and looking if it change change for example doing `data: 'action=2'`

Anyway unless you have control on the remote machine you cannot clearly see the code

Comment: Thanks a lot bro! usefull answer.